# Group generated by self-inverse elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, dihedral-groups

Given objects $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$, is there a name for the group generated by $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ subject only to the relations $x_i^2 = 1$ for all $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$?

The [dihedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) seems similar (generated by reflections) but has more relations.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but maybe relevant: [Coxeter groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group).  Actually, this looks even better: [Reflection groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_group).

Comment: Note that these groups are infinite for $n > 1$.

Comment: It's also called the free product of $n$ copies of the cyclic group of order $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This group is known as the universal [Coxeter group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group) on $n$ generators. Every Coxeter group on $n$ generators is a quotient of this group. There is a corresponding Kac-Moody group, Lie algebra, generalized flag variety, etc. It has been known for some time that its [Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%E2%80%93Lusztig_polynomial) have positive integer coefficients. A reference is Combinatorics of Coxeter groups by Bjorner and Brenti.